# Debugging crash and memory leak

Tags: debugging

We are developing a plugin for outlook in visual basic 6.0.We have been facing issues like outlook crash ( due to some objects not getting destroyed or some other reason). One way we have been solving this issue is reading code,commenting code( to observe the affect), logging etc. Are there any other ways of debugging? Are there tools which will help us in knowing what objects are held in memory?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the [Debugging tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.mspx#a).

They take a little time to get used to, but the crash dumps can be very helpful...